# PHP: Output only once for the same post id and add media of that post

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am sorry about the question title but I don't get any proper word to define.

I have multiple medias for the same post in table now I want to output data in below format

```
Post ID 1
------------------------
media1, media2, media3
------------------------

Post ID 2
------------------------
media1, media2, media3
------------------------

so on...
```

Here is table image
[image]

I have join above table using below query

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_author, wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_status, wp_posts.post_type, 
wp_review_media.post_id, wp_review_media.user_id, wp_review_media.id, wp_review_media.image_name, wp_review_media.`status`, 
wp_users.ID, wp_users.user_login

FROM wp_posts
RIGHT OUTER JOIN wp_users ON wp_users.ID = wp_posts.post_author
RIGHT OUTER JOIN wp_review_media ON wp_posts.ID = wp_review_media.post_id

WHERE wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' AND wp_review_media.`status` = 0
```

Currently it is giving output in below format with this loop

```
<?php
if ($medias) {
    foreach ($medias as $media) {
?> 
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $media->ID; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $media->post_title; ?></td>

        </tr>
<?php } 
} else { ?>
        <tr>
        <td>No Record Found!</td>
        <tr>  
<?php } ?>
```

Output:

```
Post ID 1
---------
media1

Post ID 1
---------
media2

Post ID 1
---------
media3

Post ID 2
---------
media1

Post ID 2
---------
media2

Post ID 2
---------
media3

so on....
```

So can anyone help me to understand how can I get the result I describe above.

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just want the id and the list of medias, use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID, GROUP_CONCAT(wp_posts.post_title) titles
FROM wp_posts
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN wp_users ON wp_users.ID = wp_posts.post_author
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN wp_review_media ON wp_posts.ID = wp_review_media.post_id
WHERE wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' AND wp_review_media.`status` = 0
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
```

Comment: This will only output post titles right? than I need to run another query to get medias? Am I thinking in right way?

Comment: @pixelngrain -- not exactly sure what you're asking.  Given your php code above, using GROUP_CONCAT will produce the Post Id and Post_Titles all in a single row (PostId1; Title1,Title2,Title3) vs (PostId1;Title1 -- PostId1;Title2 -- etc).  Good luck.

Comment: if you refer my diagram than I want all post id groped and all media of that post id should display under that group. I have tried by running multiple query but than it is some how rendering all media to all post

Comment: @pixelngrain -- using GROUP_CONCAT, you'll get just that -- it will print out a single PostId and then a list of Media.  Give it a try with your above php code.  Now that is printing everything beside each other.  If you truly want post id then line break then medias, make 2 TRs instead of 2 TDs.